# GPU only visible in clinfo for root

Tags: server, amd-graphics, opencl

If I just run `clinfo` in a terminal, only my CPU is visible. But, if I run `sudo clinfo` my GPU suddenly appears. As far as I can tell, my GPU is not able to run any opencl code. Any thoughts?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 with an R9 390 AMD card.

Comment: Same problem I have. I found the solution and It works. https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/62

Answer (score 1):

A bit late here, but I was having the same issue. My issue was that the `/dev/dri/renderD129` had the wrong permissions.

I fixed it with `sudo chmod 0666 /dev/dri/renderD129`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, here: https://github.com/hughperkins/cltorch/issues/74#issuecomment-222333852

The solution is that you have to do `sudo su` and run from root.